# Split a column in R into two

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a column in my data frame having values like

[image]

I want the resultant Dataframe of the format:

[image]

Comment: `str_split_fixed` try this one

Comment: @Frank I will remove the regex tag shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF$Col5 <- gsub('/.*?/','', DF$Col1)
```

Comment: Had an extra dot.

Comment: Seems bizarrely dependent on the length of the path. Tbh, I have no idea how it's meant to work but it fails with...`gsub('/.*?/','', c("/A/B/C/abc", "/abc"))`. Probably, you just want the `basename` function.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the dot.  Frank, I assumed these were not file paths and were a list of companies or something in the strict format listed.

Comment: @Frank The multiple slashes in your example would require a different pattern. Balter's solution matches the first forward slash, then more than one of any character, until another forward slash is matched.

Comment: @Mako212 Ok, thanks, I get it now.

Comment: @Frank Check my updated answer for matching your example

Comment: Yeah, that's better / more general (assuming I'm right about what the OP is after). Thanks